# Animation object going down vertically (Z) based on a matplotlib plot / based on a list

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I have programmed a simple code of rocket landing just based on its height.

A function is running so that the rocket boosts when it needs to, so it will land safe. A safe landing is accomplished when the speed is <5.

Now I'm trying to code an animation, maybe with pygame, where the rocket will be shown, when it goes down.
I think it's pretty simple, but I don't have an experience with pygame or such animations.

My current code is:

```
import numpy 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

#Mondlandung

h=10000
v=0
v_Landung=5                               
gmond=2
m_Rack=5000
m_Treib=1500
m_Gesamt=0            
delta_t=1                                        
t=0
a=0
F_g=0
F_lw=0
F_resul=0
F_Schub=0
Schub=0
h_Liste=[]
v_Liste=[]
a_Liste=[]
t_Liste=[]
m_Treib_Liste=[]

while h >=0:
    if m_Treib <=0:
        Schub=0
        print("Ihr Treibstoff ist leer!")
    elif h<=719:                             
        a=(v-v_Landung)/(h/v)
        Schub=(a*m_Rack+F_g)/2000
        if a<29.4:                               
            a=(v-v_Landung)/(h/v)
            time.sleep(1)
            Schub=(a*m_Rack+F_g)/2000
        else:
            a=29.4
            time.sleep(1)
            Schub=(a*m_Rack+F_g)/2000
    else:
        Schub = 0
        
    F_Schub=Schub*2000
    m_Treib=m_Treib-Schub*delta_t
    m_Gesamt=m_Rack+m_Treib
    F_g=(m_Gesamt)*gmond
    F_resul=-F_g+F_Schub
    a=F_resul/m_Rack
    v=v+(-a)*delta_t
    h=h-v*delta_t
    t=t+delta_t
    
    h_Liste.append(h)
    v_Liste.append(v)
    a_Liste.append(a)
    t_Liste.append(t)
    m_Treib_Liste.append(m_Treib)
    
    layout="h={:6.1f} v={:6.1f} a={:6.1f} m_Treib={:6.1f} t={:6.1f} Schub={:6.1f}"
    print(layout.format(h,v,a,m_Treib,t,Schub,end="  "))

if v<=5:
    print("Weiche Landung")
elif 5<v<=20:
    print("Harte Landung")
else:
    print("Bruchlandung")
    

x = t_Liste
plt.figure(num=1, figsize=(15, 8))
plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=None, hspace=0.7)
plt.subplot(4,1,1)
plt.scatter(x, h_Liste, c="blue", marker="x")
plt.plot(x, h_Liste, color="red", linewidth=2, linestyle="dashed", label="H")
plt.xlabel("t in s")
plt.ylabel("h in m")
plt.legend()
plt.title("Höhenveränderung")

plt.subplot(4,1,2)
plt.scatter(x, v_Liste, c="blue", marker="x")
plt.plot(x, v_Liste, color="red", linewidth=2, linestyle="dotted", label="V")
plt.xlabel("t in s")
plt.ylabel("v in m/s")
plt.legend()
plt.title("Geschwindigkeitsveränderung")

plt.subplot(4,1,3)
plt.scatter(x, a_Liste, c="blue", marker="x")
plt.plot(x, a_Liste, color="red", linewidth=2, linestyle="dashed", label="A")
plt.xlabel("t in s")
plt.ylabel("a in m/s²")
plt.legend()
plt.title("Beschleunigungsveränderung")

plt.subplot(4,1,4)
plt.scatter(x, m_Treib_Liste, c="blue", marker="x")
plt.plot(x, m_Treib_Liste, color="red", linewidth=2, linestyle="dotted")
plt.xlabel("t in s")
plt.ylabel("m in kg")
plt.title("Treibstoffverbauch")
plt.show()
```

Comment: I've removed the [tag:pygame] tag. The [tag:pygame] tag addresses the [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news) library, but is not intended for a game written in Python.

Comment: What is the question here?